How does the axiom of specification resolve Russell's paradox?
I've had some trouble understanding exactly how ZFC prevents Russell's paradox and most textbooks I read don't provide a justification for this. Up till now, here's my understanding.
Russell's paradox arises from the unrestricted axiom of comprehension:
$$\exists X \forall x(X = \{x\;|\;S(x)\})$$
This means that $x\in X\iff S(x)$.
Now, if I declare $S(x)$ to be the statement that $x\not\in x$, then you have the Russell set: $R = \{x\;|\;x\not\in x\}$. The paradox is that $R\in R\implies R\not\in R$ and $R\not\in R\implies R\in R$.
Although I haven't seen this in any of the textbooks I've read, here's my understanding for how the following axiom (axiom of separation) solves this paradox:
$$\forall A\exists B \forall x(B = \{x\;|\;x\in A\land S(x)\}$$
This means that $x\in B\iff x\in A\land S(x)$
Now, if we try creating a similar set as Russell's set, we see that it isn't possible. Let's say I write $B =\{x\;|\;x\in A\land x\not\in x\}$. Now, $B\in B\implies B\in A\land B\not\in B$. For $B\in A\land B\not\in B$ to be true, $B\not\in B$. This is a contradiction. However, now consider $B\not\in B$. $B\not\in B\implies \neg(B\in A\land B\not\in B)$. Now, we can rewrite and say that $B\not\in B\implies \neg (B\in A)\lor\neg(B\not\in B)$. Or, in other words, $B\not\in B\implies (B\not\in A)\lor(B\in B)$. Now there isn't necessarily a contradiction if we can show that $B\not\in A$. To show this, is it enough to just show that $B\in A$ leads to a contradiction, namely Russell's paradox? And does my reasoning justify the axiom of specification?

Russell's paradox arises in naive set theory because it has the axiom of unrestricted comprehension. ZFC does not have the unrestricted comprehension axiom, and so it does not suffer from this problem.

A very common misconception amongst non-set theorists is that Russell's paradox does not arise in ZFC because it has axioms like regularity or specification. This claim does not make sense: you cannot get rid of an inconsistency in an axiom system by adding new axioms to it! See here for more details.

What you have there is a failure to derive a contradiction in a similar manner to Russell’s paradox. Instead you have a proof that $B\notin B$ and  $B\notin A$… and since there’s no evidence to the contrary of either of those two statements, there is no obvious contradiction here. This is not a proof that there’s no possible way you could find a case where $B\in A$ and get a contradiction, or derive a contradiction from ZFC in some other way, it just shows that the original source of contradiction appears to be tamed. (And of course no one has yet found a contradiction in ZFC.)

See this post

FYI - the unrestricted axiom of comprehension is $$\exists X\forall x(x\in X \iff S(x)}$$ The notation ${x\mid S(x)}$ depends on that axiom (or its restricted version) for its definition. Futher $x$ is only a dummy variable in it, thus not available for quantization outside of it.
